# Optional nested JSON object with Spring RestTemplate

Tags: json, spring, resttemplate

In the API I'm trying to use with Spring RestTemplate I'm receiving an optional field as shown in the example below.
This optional field is a nested object and I would like to use a nested class to map it.

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30
}
```

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30,
  "car": {
    "year": 1984,
    "color": "red"
  }
}
```

My current class definition:

```
public class User {
    public class Car {
        @Getter
        @Setter
        public String color;

        @Getter
        @Setter
        public Integer year;
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public String name;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public Integer age;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public Car car;
}
```

With the invocation:

```
ResponseEntity<User> response = restTemplate.exchange("http://....", HttpMethod.POST, request, User.class);
```

I get the following exception:

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of '....User$Car' (although at least one Creator exists): can only instantiate non-static inner class by using default, no-argument constructor`

How could I have the `car` property either `null` or instantiated with `Car` class if the node is present in the json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try with the below updated class. Change is defining the inner class as static.

```
public  class User {
    public static class Car {
        @Getter
        @Setter
        public String color;

        @Getter
        @Setter
        public Integer year;
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public String name;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public Integer age;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public Car car;
}
```